# How to show/hide ExtJS.Toolbar button programmatically

Tags: javascript, extjs, show

I am attempting to show/hide an ExtJS Toolbar button programmatically. I have tried to access the button directly, by ID using:

```
var btn = Ext.get('buttonID'); // I've also tried Ext.query('buttonID')
btn.show();
```

However, this does not cause the button to be shown. The toolbar button is defined with the ID with which I am attempting to execute the `show()` method.

Is there a different way for me to access the button, directly?  Or, is there a different way to show it (adding/removing CSS attributes, etc.)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to *show* a button, which is not visible, then do

```
// Button definition
var btn = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Press me!',
    visible: false,
    id: 'myButton'
});

// Now show the button.
var theSameButton = Ext.getCmp('myButton');
btn.setVisible(true);
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you, a million times over.  I'm pretty new to ExtJS (long-time jQuery user) and I'm fumbling through a lot of this stuff :).

Comment: thank you, this works for me too! </useless comment that doesn't add to conversatioN>

Answer (score 1):

The 'visible' property only works in 4.1.1+

http://jsfiddle.net/mf2jH/24/

Comment: Well, as far as I remember, my answer was targeted ExtJS 3.x, which was the version I worked with at that time.